# finding the derivative of a polynomial

Tags: python, math

I wondering symbolically how you would parse a polynomial into a function and return the derivative. What data structure would I use or method to parse the polynomial? Preferably without using any libraries, as this question could pop up in a technical interview.

```
polynomial-> of nth degree

def derivative(polynomial):
    return derivative

Example:

f(x)  = 2x^2+3x+1
f'(x) = 4x+3
```

I don't want a solution, this is not homework but a hint of where I would start.

Comment: When I tried this once I just used a list of ints to store all coefficients. That's not very elaborate, but it did work, and doesn't use much space.

Answer (score 17):

A polynomial in a single variable can be represented simply as an array containing the coefficients. So for example 1 + 5x<sup>3</sup> - 29x<sup>5</sup> can be expressed as `[1, 0, 0, 5, 0, -29]`.  Expressed in this form the derivative is easy to compute.

suppose `poly` is a python list as above. Then

```
deriv_poly = [poly[i] * i for i in range(1, len(poly))]
```

For sparse polynomial other representations are relatively easy, such as a list of pairs `(coefficient, exponent)` or dictionary mapping exponents to coefficients.

Parsing the expression is more complicated but using various parsing frameworks should be easy because the grammar is comparatively simple.

Comment: If my math is still proper, may be you would need an additional: `deriv_poly = deriv_poly[1:]` ..

Comment: @Thrustmaster no, that's why the `range` starts at `1`. A perhaps-too-clever trick :) I would write it using the slice and `enumerate`: `[i * term for i, term in enumerate(poly[1:])]`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Ah, I overlooked that. +1 to Greg :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: `, 1` is missing.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, enumerate always starts with i=0, regardless of how you have sliced the sequence being enumerated, unless you specify the start argument.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Yes, and I intend to st - oh, no, wait, no I don't... I want to multiply the first element by 1. Damn it >_<

Answer (score 5):

In my experience matrices are often very useful in representing polynomials

Comment: so 2x^2+3x+1 would become [2,3,1], but the array would scale to nth degree

Comment: it's more useful to represent it as [1, 3, 2], so the i-th element of the list would be the coefficient of x^i

Answer (score 5):

I came up with this now. What you want is this:

1. Parse the polynomial: you need to have a predefined pattern. The more "untrusted" or "wild" the input is, the better you will have to parse it. You could use regular expressions.
2. Have the basic components of the equation (coeff, power_of_x) list.
3. Do the math (derivative formula)
4. Return an equation the way the input was given.

This gives you:

```
import re

def read(eq):
    terms = eq.split('+')
    equation = [re.split('x\^?', t) for t in terms]
    eq_map = []
    for e in equation:
        try:
            coeff = int(e[0])
        except ValueError:
            coeff = 1
        try:
            power = int(e[1])
        except ValueError:
            power = 1
        except IndexError:
            power = 0
        eq_map.append((coeff, power))
    return eq_map

def write(eq_map):
    def str_power(p):
        if p == 0:
            return ''
        elif p == 1:
            return 'x'
        else:
            return 'x^%d' % (p,)

    def str_coeff(c):
        return '' if c == 1 else str(c)
    str_terms = [(str_coeff(c) + str_power(p)) for c, p in eq_map]
    return "+".join(str_terms)

def derivative(eq):
    eq_map = read(eq)
    der_map = [(p*c, p-1) for c, p in eq_map[:-1]]
    return write(der_map)

def run(eq):
    print eq, '->', derivative(eq)

run("2x^2+3x+1")
run("x^3+2x^2+1")
```

This is very basic. For example: `2*x^3` will not work because of the "*". Of course there are many cases in which it won't work, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: `re` is Python's regular expression module. It is used to identify and split certain parts of the equation according to patterns (e.g. the letter "x" followed by an optional "^" sign in this case)

Comment: Okay sure ! Good to know

Answer (score 3):

Well, I believe the starting point would be to define the basic components of the expression.

When you look at a function and want to process it like that, it's basically a grammar, it can be a bit complicated depending on how much detail you want to allow.

Your grammar has the form of EXPRESSION.

EXPRESSION can be either:
TERM (where your function is basically something like nx^y)
or 
TERM OPERATOR EXPRESSION

If you can parse a function like this, you simply need to define the rules for handling a TERM, and then recursively apply the same method for the rest of the expression.

Your polynomial will always have the form nx^y, with some simplifications for cases where y is 0 or 1, or when n is 1 and is omitted.

This is how I would approach it without using any additional libs. If you want, I can try and explain my point further.

By the way, I know my answer doesn't exactly address Python or the data structures to use, but it is one possible way of approaching this kind of problems.

Comment: so you could have a class representing a term and then apply the grammar rules accordingly

Comment: A class is one option, yes. This problem can be as complex as you want it to be, depending on things like... do you assume the polynomial to already be simplified? do you allow negative powers? How about roots? ;) This approach guarantees that you have your derivative rules concentrated in one place.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses iterables where the i-th element is the coefficient of x^i, so for *p(x) = 3*x^5 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + 5* the input would be `[5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3]`. The derivate is *p'(x) = 15*x^4  + 6*x^2 + 2*x*, so the expected result should be `[0, 2, 6, 0, 15]`.

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> coeff = [5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
>>> print list(itertools.imap(operator.mul, itertools.islice(coeff, 1, None), itertools.count(1)))
[0, 2, 6, 0, 15]
```

**Update**: I wanted to be really tricky here using iterators and all, but my solution turned out to be more than twice as slow as GregS's. Somebody could explain me from where it came this slowness?

```
>>> print timeit.repeat("poly(coeff)", "poly = lambda coeff: [coeff[i] * i for i in range(1, len(coeff))]; coeff = [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, -29]")
[1.7786244418210748, 1.7956598059847046, 1.7500179643792024]
>>> print timeit.repeat("poly(coeff)", "import operator, itertools; poly = lambda coeff: list(itertools.imap(operator.mul, itertools.islice(coeff, 1, None), itertools.count(1))); coeff = [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, -29]")
[4.01759841913463, 4.152715700867423, 5.195021813889031]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pretty or concrete solution, but you can improve it :)
Used dictionary to store coefficients and their powers, with powers as keys.

```
import re
def polynomial(data):
    coeffs = {}
    splits = map(str.strip, re.split(r"([+ \-])",data))
    sign = 1
    for p in splits:
        if p in "+-":
            sign = 1 if p == '+' else -1
            continue
        s = re.split('[^0-9]+', p)
        coeff = int(s[0])
        if len(s) == 1:
            pow = 0
        elif s[1] == '':
            pow = 1
        else:
            pow = int(s[1])
        coeffs[pow] = sign * coeff
    return coeffs

def derive(poly):
    return dict([(p-1, p*c) for p,c in poly.items() if p != 0])

def print_poly(poly, var = 'x'):
    print(''.join(['{0}{1}{2}^{3}'.format('+-'[c<0],c,var,p) for p,c in sorted(poly.items(), reverse = True)]))
```

Comment: `derive` could be re-written `{(p-1): (p*c) for p,c in poly.items() if p != 0}` instead of creating a list of tuples and using `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

If the polynomial equation is given as a list. For eg: p=[9,4,12,2]
return value will be [27, 8, 12]

```
     def derivative(p):
        derv=[]
        for i in range(len(p)-1):
            derv.append((len(p)-i-1)*p[i])
        return derv
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines 7 and 8 will extract coefficients and exponents in lists regardless of the sign.
Lines 13 and 14 remove empty strings from lists.
This is not perfect, but it is simpler:

```
import pdb;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
import re;                                                                      


poly = input("Input the polynomial you want to find its derivative : ")         

coefficients = re.split("x\^[+-]?[0-9]+",poly)                                  
exponents = re.split("[+-]?[0-9]+x\^",poly)                                     

print(coefficients)                                                            
print(exponents)                                                               

coefficients = [ i for i in coefficients if i !='']                             
exponents = [i for i in exponents if i !='']                                    

print(coefficients)                                                            
print(exponents)                                                               

derivative=""                                                                   
for i in range(len(coefficients)):                                              
    print(coefficients[i])                                                      
    print(exponents[i])                                                         
    coefficient = int(coefficients[i])*int(exponents[i])                        
    exponent = int(exponents[i]) - 1                                            
    if exponent == 0:                                                           
        derivative +=  str(coefficient)                                         
    else:                                                                       
        derivative +=  str(coefficient) + "x^" + str(exponent)                  

print("The original value is {0}".format(poly))                                 
print("The derivative is {0}".format(derivative))
```